# Can I use Syntax Highlighter by Alex Gorbatchev with Windows Command Prompt commands in Blogger?

Tags: blogger, blog, syntax-highlighting

I use [Syntax Highlighter by Alex Gorbatchev](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) in my blog on Blogger. It perfectly works with all the programming languages I use. Recently I needed to highlight Windows Command Prompt commands and I found only `brush: powershell` option for the `<pre>` tag to do it. Unfortunately, it does not work exactly as I need.

I have theses commands:

```
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
del IconCache.db /a
shutdown /r /f /t 00
```

When I use `<pre class="brush: powershell; gutter: false">CODE_GOES_HERE</pre>`, it highlights `cd`, `del` and `/r` (not a command at all) but does not highlight `taskkill` and `shutdown` as I expect it to.

Is there any workaround to solve this problem and highlight Windows Command Prompt commands correctly or should I use another syntax highlighter in my blog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of different brushes that you can add to the script to support several other languages, among which are batch files (bat, cmd, batch):

http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/list-of-brushes-syntaxhighligher/

Comment: Thanks! As I understood it is only possible when you host Syntax Highlighter on your own server, right?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can include the brushes code as part of your template and that should do the trick. Of course, it will make your template bigger for every page, even when you don't use it. Check here for some guidance on how to do that: http://geektalkin.blogspot.com/2009/11/embed-code-syntax-highlighting-in-blog.html